# django form pagination save in local storage

Tags: jquery, django, pagination, local-storage

I have a form pagination that I want to save user's input in local storage. I have managed to get this variable in my jquery script:

> var fields = [<django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object at
>   0x000000000E415D30>, <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object
>   at 0x000000000E415400>, <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField
>   object at 0x000000000E415390>,
>   <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object at
>   0x000000000E415AC8>, <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object
>   at 0x000000000E415BE0>, <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField
>   object at 0x000000000E415208>,
>   <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object at
>   0x000000000E4158D0>, <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object
>   at 0x000000000E4154E0>, <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField
>   object at 0x000000000E415860>,
>   <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object at
>   0x000000000E80DEF0>]

My problem is I do not know how to save this field objects' key/value into local storage. There are large number of pages so this is generic and I should not use field names to access field values, just this field objects.

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: It really depends how you're going to use what to put in the local storage. Are you doing this in order to re-populate the form when the user goes backwards? It's not clear what kind of keys and values you need. But in general, the property `id_for_label` of a `BoundField` will give you the `id` of the HTML input element and the method `value()` will give you the field's value as rendered in HTML. So instead of passing the list of BoundFields to your template, you can create a dictionary with the `id` and `value` of each `BoundField` which you can then store locally.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am doing this in order to re-populate the form when the user goes backward.

Comment: I am going to try your general suggestion. I will post the result for the sake of others.

Comment: I did not understand when you said: "But in general, the property id_for_label of a BoundField will give you the id of the HTML input element and the method value() will give you the field's value as rendered in HTML."

Comment: I did not understand... Are you refering to template html code? If so, below is my html code where elements is constructed in view from paginator = Paginator(boundfield_list, 10); elements = paginator.page(page); return render(request, 'rsmgui_input.html', {'elements': elements}). Here is the html part: <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% for field in elements %}
<label  for="field_label">{{ field.label }}</label>
<div id="field_label" {{ field }}</div> </div>
{% endfor %}
</form> Explain ur general comment in this context.

Comment: Somewhere you have `var fields = {{ ... }}` in your template (to set the var in your script). There, instead of just setting this to the list of fields, you should set it to a dictionary of key value pairs, where the key is the `id_for_label` and the value is the `value()` of your fields.

Comment: I found that django BoundField class has two methods "id_for_label" and "value()". So I can create a dict[boundfile.id_for_label] = boundfield .value(). However, because I am using pagination, template need the elements = paginator.page(page) to be passed to it, how the dictionary can compensate for this?  As you mentioned  I want to re-populate the form when the user goes backwards.  Does it help if I post all part of my code?

Comment: I don't know how your set of pages work, you asked how to get something more useful as `var fields` for your javascript. It's not clear, if each page is rendered separately by django, why do you need to store this locally if you have the values on the server?

Comment: Thanks. I now understand what did you mean. Ignore my last comment. Now I am trying to make a dictionary. I tried two version of my fields = {{"elements"}. Neither one seems correct. Pls correct me: var obj = {};
    $("{{elements}}").each(function() {
        obj[$(this).attr('id_for_label')] = $(this).attr('value()');
    });
    $("{{elements}}").each(function() {
        obj[$(this).id_for_label] = $(this).value());
    });

Comment: In response to your comment "I don't know how your set of pages work..." I have 5 pages of forms and I want user be able to go back and forth between the forms and using local storage preserve their input.

Comment: dirkgroten - I am afraid to get disconnected from your due to this message "Please avoid extended discussions in comments...". Because I do not have enough reputation, I can not do chat with you either. My e-mail is trimbleAva@gmail.com if somehow I lose connection. Thanks

Comment: No, you have to do this in Python, in your view, not in javascript.  you should replace your python context variable `elements` by the dict: `elements = {field.id_for_label: field.value() for field in elements}`. Then in your script `var fields = {{ elements }}` as before. Now you have a javascript dictionary of key/values that you can store and manipulate.

Comment: Many thanks to dirkgroten for his comments. It helped me greately to find my way to a solution. For those with same problem, below are my cleaned up code for the purpose of demonstration. I hope it helps. See next comment ...

Answer (score 0):

```
forms.py file
=============
class ControlElementForm(BaseForm):
    rundescriptor = forms.CharField(max_length=50, initial='rsmgui', label='Run Descriptor')
    typechoices = [(0, 'hour'), (1, 'minute'), (2, 'day')]
    tstype = forms.ChoiceField(choices=typechoices, label='Time Step',
                               widget=forms.Select())

    lenchoices = [(0, 24), ]
    tslen = forms.ChoiceField(choices=lenchoices, label='Time Length',
                              widget=forms.Select())

    svchoices = [(0, "PETSC"),]
    solver = forms.ChoiceField(choices=svchoices, label="Solver Package", help_text="Portable, Extensible Toolkit for Scientific Computation")
    mchoices = [(0, "gmres"),]
    method = forms.ChoiceField(choices=mchoices, label="Solver Method")
    alpha = forms.FloatField(max_value=1.0, min_value=0.0, initial=0.900)
    cchoices = [(0, "ilu"),]
    precond = forms.ChoiceField(choices=cchoices, label='Pre Condition') # TODO ask the meaning
    uchoices = [(0, "english"),]
    units = forms.ChoiceField(choices=uchoices)

views.py file
============
def rsminput(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = XMLElementsForm(request.POST)
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        if form.is_valid():
            # do something
            messages.success(request, 'Your data was saved successfully!')
            return render(request, 'rsmgui_home.html')
        else:
            messages.error(request, form.errors)

    boundfield_list = tuple(XMLElementsForm())  
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(boundfield_list, 10)

    try:
        elements = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        elements = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        elements = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'rsmgui_input.html', {'elements': elements })


urls.py file
=============
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

from .views import rsminput

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^input$', rsminput, name='rsminput'),
]

rsmgui_input.html file
==========================
{% extends "rsmgui_nav.html" %}
{% block title %}RSM Input{% endblock %}

<script src="{% static 'jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'jquery/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>

{% block center_menu %}

<form class="form-horizontal" id="input-form" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-sm-7">
        <p>Model Input:&nbsp;&lt;Control Elements&gt;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-5 text-right">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="input-xml">
                <button id="input-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-trans" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="save">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-trans" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="reset">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                </button>
                <button id="input-close" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-trans"
                      data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="close">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div >
        {% for boundfield in elements %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-5" style="text-align:right;"
                    for="{{boundfield.id_for_label}}">{{ boundfield.label }}
              </label>
              <div class="col-sm-7" id="{{boundfield.id_for_label}}"
                    aria-describedby="{{boundfield.id_for_label}} | addstr:ex">{{ boundfield }}
              </div>
            </div>

            {% if boundfield.help_text %}
                <p class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> <small style="color: grey">{{ boundfield.help_text|safe }}</small></p>
            {% endif %}

            {% for error in boundfield.errors %}
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"><span class="text-danger small">{{ error }}</span></div>
            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <!-- For pagination-->
    <div class="text-center">
        {% if elements.has_other_pages %}
            <ul class="pagination">
                {% if elements.has_previous %}
                    <li><a href="?page={{ elements.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
                {% endif %}

                {% for i in elements.paginator.page_range %}
                    {% if elements.number == i %}
                        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}

                {% if elements.has_next %}
                    <li><a href="?page={{ elements.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function loadInputLocalStorage(){
            $('#input-form :input').each(function(){
                var key = $(this).attr('id');
                if(localStorage.getItem(key)) {
                    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
                    $(this).val(value);
                }
            });
        }
        loadInputLocalStorage();

        function saveInputLocalStorage() {
            $('#input-form :input').each(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var value = $(this).val();
                localStorage.setItem(id, value);

            });
        }
        $('#input-submit').on('click', function(){
            saveInputLocalStorage();
        });

    }); // end of document
</script>
```